# Find a change level and a text of the change in a .rst news files using regex

Tags: python, regex

## What I want

I'm trying to work out a way in which I can use regex to find two groups in RST news files. I want get change level as well as the change text, for instance a following `.rst` file:

- hence I want a following regex **(changelevel): (change text)**
- I was thinking about something like **(changelevel): (anything until no next change level)**

```
* Major: This is a **Major** change
* Minnor: This is is a minor change with a typo
* Patch: This
is a multiline
  patch
```

Should return a match, group1 and group2 as following

#### Match 1:

```
"* Major: This is a **Major** change"
"* Major: "
"This is a major **Major** change"
```

#### Match 2:

```
"* Patch: This\nis a multiline\n  patch"
"* Patch: "
"This\nis a multiline\n  patch
```

## What I need help with

I cannot make a regex that will take care of multilines and asterisks present in the "change text"
I tried following logic

1. Match the change level `^(\*\s+(\w+):\s)`
2. Match anything - with "dot matches newline" option turned on" `.*`
3. Negative forward lookup until I match the change level `(?!^(\*\s+(\w+):\s))`

- I ended up with `^(\*\s+(\w+):\s).*(?!^(\*\s+(\w+):\s))` but `.*` seems to just match everything to group 2

[image]

## What works

I managed to get the first group working with a following regex which works works:

- beginning of the line
- star in front
- then whitespace
- a word
- colon
- white space

`^(\*\s+(\w+):\s)`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you can write the pattern using the lookahead and introduce matching a newline and if the assertions succeeds, then match the whole line.

```
^(\*\s+\w+:\s)(.*(?:\n(?!\*\s+\w+:\s).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\*\s+\w+:\s` match `*`, 1+ whitespace chars, 1+ word chars, `:` and a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole
  - `\n` Match a newline

    - `(?!\*\s+\w+:\s)` The negative lookahead, asserting not the starting pattern here
    - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to match alles lines
- `)` Close group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eTCpoO/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/uYRSxS).

Example code:

```
import re
 
pattern = r"^(\*\s+\w+:\s)(.*(?:\n(?!\*\s+\w+:\s).*)*)"
 
s = ("* Major: This is a **Major** change\n"
    "* Minnor: This is is a minor change with a typo\n"
    "* Patch: This\n"
    "is a multiline\n"
    "  patch")
 
result = re.findall(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```

Output

```
[('* Major: ', 'This is a **Major** change'), ('* Minnor: ', 'This is is a minor change with a typo'), ('* Patch: ', 'This\nis a multiline\n  patch')]
```

Comment: I really liked yours. It's very elegant. I'm just leaving my edits for it here, as OP is my colleague, and I know what the use case is, but I want him to choose your answer. https://regex101.com/r/vOe0oP/1

Comment: Thanks @the-fourth-bird your solution seems to be working and as Techbech mentioned it's very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r'(\*\s*\w+:\s*)([\s\S]*?(?=\n\*\s*\w+:\s*|$))',text)
```

- Use `\n`ewline followed by `*` or end of string `$` as a anchor
- Group 1: A literal `*` followed by zero or more `\s`paces and any `\w`ord character, a literal `:` and one or more `\s`paces
- Group 2: Match everything non greedily `*?` upto `\n\*\s*\w+:\s*`(like Group 1) or `$`

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't think it works with bold text being at the start of the line - https://regex101.com/r/GNw4g2/1

Comment: @BartekLachowicz Thanks for responding. I made the anchor more specific.